# how to save and load a object in a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible in a WP7 app to save some objects which i create and then load it when the app is started again?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look to store persistent items into IsolatedStorage. You can see an overview and an example of how to use [IsolatedStorage here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626522%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). There are also a range of examples on [this site](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage), showing how to save different types of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example storing a string, but you should be able to store any type of object this way.
Add IsolatedStorage to your references:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

In your class:

```
private string myString;
```

In the Loaded event for your page:

```
try
{
    myString = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["myString"];
}
catch
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("myString", "this value is a string");
}
```

and later, when you want to save:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["myString"] = myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

try after
the example code above to add this.
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.save